# Adding id attribute on Buefy table

Tags: buefy

I cannot find a way to set id attribute on Buefy table (b-table element). It makes automated tests for my application very fragile when there is no possibility to identify elements by id.

Comment: I wouldn't suppose the obvious `<b-table id="whatever">` worked?

Comment: You can't wrap b-table element in a div? Also source code of b-table here: https://github.com/buefy/buefy/blob/dev/src/components/table/Table.vue